# Bash Conditional String and Integer together

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, gnu

I am trying to do both integer and string comparison in a statement as follows:

```
$ TimeHr=$(date +%_H)
$ Time=Night
$ echo TimeHr
1

$ if ((TimeHr>18 || TimeHr<5 )) && [ Time == "Night" ]; then echo "Night Time"; else echo "Day Time"; fi
Day Time

$ if ((TimeHr>18 || TimeHr<5 )) && [[ Time == "Night" ]]; then echo "Night Time"; else echo "Day Time"; fi
Day Time
```

But it is not printing the correct if-branch. How should I modify it?

---

Edit:

I prefer to use `((` for numerical comparisons as the code looks more understandable.

Comment: Crawl before you leap high hurdles.  If your attempt to combine three tests into one doesn't work, try to get a single test working.   P.S. For what you're doing, there's no reason to include the `_` in `+%_H`.

Comment: @G-Man I am not sure, but I think I did this to remove the leading 0, to prevent the number to be interpreted as octal form.

Comment: OK, good point; I had overlooked that issue.  It looks like ```+%-H``` would work as well.

Comment: @G-Man What is the difference between `_` and `-` here?

Comment: `_` replaces the leading zero with a space (``⁠ 7``), ``-`` simply outputs numbers less than ten as a single digit, with nothing in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would combine the two conditionals into a single one

```
if [[ ( $TimeHr -gt 18 || $TimeHr -lt 5 ) && $Time == "Night" ]]; then echo "Night Time"; else echo "Day Time"; fi
Night Time
```

However your original test has a simple error; inside the `[` and  `[[` tests you need to use `$variable` and not just `variable`.

So

```
if ((TimeHr>18 || TimeHr<5 )) && [[ $Time == "Night" ]]; then echo "Night Time"; else echo "Day Time"; fi
```